# Gnome shell "show desktop" shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, window-management

I been thinking of anyone could guide me up, that in ubuntu 11.10 with gnome 3,
there is a option <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to show the desktop by minimizing the current window.

What I was thinking was that if I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> it will lead to desktop screen and when 
I press again <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to go back to my working window..

As of now it doesnt work in this way ..is there any way out to do that same

Comment: try "xdotool" in scrip

Answer (score 35):

### With Gnome Shell (17.10+)

The default keybind is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>. The setting is called `Hide all normal windows`

You can change it in Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts > Navigation:

[image: screenshot]

### With Unity (before 17.10)

The [patch](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643609) is already released but if you still face that problem use the following:

- Click your username on the top right of the screen and select `System Settings`.
- Under `Hardware` click `Keyboard.`
- Switch to the Shortcuts tab, and click Navigation in the left column. Scroll down and select `Hide all normal windows` which has a default value of `Disabled`.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In Ubuntu 17.10, the default is now `Ctrl+Super+D`

Comment: Suggest the Gnome developers using MS Windows' shortcut keys conventions as the default configuration, then more MS Windows users will not have difficulties to move from Windows to Linux.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a non-keyboard method, there's also the "Show desktop button" option.

Simply [**visit this link**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1194/show-desktop-button/) and click on the on/off slider near the top left corner, you'll be prompted to install the widget, and from then on you'll have a small "show desktop" icon next to "Activities in your menu". (Shown here in between my Activities menu and Google Chrome Indicator)

[image: Gnome Shell Show-Desktop Widget]

Very handy, IMHO.

Updated 25/09/2017 with the new extension compatible with the current version of GNOME Shell, as suggested by @stefan-hamke. The out-of-date original is [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/64/show-desktop-button/).

Comment: Whoever reads this and realizes that the linked extension is not compatible anymore with the current version of GNOME shell: There is an updated version available under https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1194/show-desktop-button/

Comment: That extension might be (is?) outdated.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1013739/340383 for instructions on uninstalling the old one and installing a newer one.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 12.04 beta2 (gnome-shell 3.4) you can press Super-D to show your desktop, and Super-D again to go back to your previous windows.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatic/CLI way to set the “Hide all normal windows” shorcut (in my case, to Super + D ), tested working on GNOME 45:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings show-desktop "['<Super>d']"
```

You can launch this from terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T is default keybinding on Ubuntu) or put this in your set-up shell script.