# Keyboard shortcut to show desktop in 15.10

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. I'm looking for a shortkey to "Navigate to the desktop". I saw that in previous versions of Ubuntu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> works - but it doesn't work for me in 15.10.

Do you know what the shortkey is for 15.10?

Comment: The following discussion might be useful as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/90109/gnome-shell-show-desktop-shortcut#103167

Comment: By holding `super` key` for few second, you can see the list most important keyboard shortcuts. I am using 15.10 and it uses Ctrl +Super+D for minimizing all windows and showing desktop

Answer (score 5):

I found it. It should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

You can see it under **System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Navigation → Hide All Normal Windows**

Comment: The long part of what you offered is that I have to select the desktop icon. The solution that I found brings you immediately to desktop without the need the choose the icon.

Comment: "Hide all normal windows" is disabled for me, but <Ctrl>+<Super>+D still works.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> should work.

If this doesn't there is something wrong with your machine - have you reassigned any shortcuts?

Comment: sorry. doesn't work for me.

Comment: Doesn't Super+D do anything at all?