# Too many Show Desktop extension icons under GNOME Panel

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, panel, gnome-shell-extension, show-desktop

I used the GNOME extension at [Gnome shell "show desktop" shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90109/gnome-shell-show-desktop-shortcut#comment1517282_153067) and now see too many desktop buttons. I think I might have tried to install it multiple times, apparently/maybe due to "nothing happening" each time I did so, until I realized later that it will not give any indication it actually installed something. Now I'm left with multiple "buttons" on the Panel next to the Activities navigation link:

[image]

This is under Ubuntu 17.10.

How do I remove all of them except for only one?

I do know about the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> binding but I tend to disable the bindings in the settings, as I need to have all of the Ctrl and Alt key bindings reserved for specific application windows and not "gobbled up" by the X window manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have installed an [outdated extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/64/show-desktop-button/) which may not work as expected.

Remove the extension from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) and install an updated fork of the extension:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1194/show-desktop-button/

Comment: This worked, and it removed the old icons for the outdated extension, all of them, from the activity bar, plus it added a single one that looks like a tiny house: https://i.imgur.com/wnqiYos.png