# Ubuntu BUG? SUPER+D does not maximize minimized opened windows with SUPER+D after right-click on desktop

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I have some opened windows in foreground.

If I do <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the desktop will be shown minimizing all opened windows.

It I right-click on desktop, then I can't reuse <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to maximize those windows.

How to fix that?

In the previous Ubuntu versions it worked fine.

**Edit:**

I found that this happens if do these steps:

- <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: it show the desktop
- right-click on desktop
- dismiss the contextual menu by clicking elsewhere
- <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: it does nothing

If I don't right-click on desktop <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> works.

> I'm using an LTS version, please help me **before it'll be in EOL**
>   support.

**Edit: I'm waiting for an answwer since about 4 months!!!!! Do I need to lose my reputation points by opening a bounty in order to have an answer??**

Comment: If you mean by right clicking the desktop and having the menu pop up then trying to use the shortcut to Show Desktop, I don't think it's supposed to work that way, if you mean that even after the menu closes you still cannot use the shortcut then you need to edit your question stating so.  The was it's worded it looks like expected behavior.

Comment: @TrailRider yes, I mean "even after the menu closes". I edited my question. Thanks now is clearer

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior. In Ubuntu 17.10 and above [the default is now **Ctrl+Super+D**](https://askubuntu.com/a/103167/349837), did you change it? [(here other useful GNOME shortcuts](https://askubuntu.com/a/103167/349837)).

Comment: no. I didn't changed it. Also by doing Ctrl+Super+D the same problem happens.